# Airflow API - Output of the DAG run available through API

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, airflow

I am triggering a DAG  through API as below to execute a python script to run command.

```
curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/DAG-3/dag_runs -d '{"conf":"{\"hostname\":\"<servername>\",\"username\":\"test\", \"password\":\"<password>\", \"command1\":\"uname -a\" }"}'
```

I am getting response as below when curl is executed

```
{"execution_date":"2020-07-17T18:26:58+00:00","message":"Created <DagRun DAG-3 @ 2020-07-17 18:26:58+00:00: manual__2020-07-17T18:26:58+00:00, externally triggered: True>"}
```

I can see the script executed sucessfully in DAG logs,

```
[2020-07-17 18:25:03,982] {bash_operator.py:122} INFO - Output:
[2020-07-17 18:25:04,303] {bash_operator.py:126} INFO - Linux servername 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 23 18:54:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[2020-07-17 18:25:04,321] {bash_operator.py:130} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
```

But I need this output has to be returned as JSON response, How can I achieve it.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Airflow API is asynchronous in that your `curl` simply starts a DAG run - it doesn't wait till it's complete (Because we have no way of knowing how long it will take to complete, it could be days, or weeks).

The Airflow API is still under development and AFAIK there is no way to retrieve the logs of a DAG run from it